# conditionally create/read a .plist file

Tags: ios, createfile

I want to check for the presence of a .plist file in the Documents directory. If it does **not** exist, I want to create it and seed it with the 1st entry. If it **does** exist I want to read it and append an entry to it.

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {       
    // read Faves file...
    NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    appDelegate.dictFaves = tempDict;
} else {
    NSLog(@"Creating Favorites file");
    BOOL result = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath: path contents: (NSData *)appDelegate.dictFaves attributes: nil];            
}

// .... and Append it to the list of existing favorites
[appDelegate.dictFaves setObject:newFave forKey:key];
```

1. `createFileAtPath` returns `FALSE` meaning the file was not created.
2. I question the validity of casting `appDelegate.dictFaves` to `(NSDATA *)`. If that is unwise, how to I create a file with a `Dictionary`?

Comment: casting to `NSData *` directly a dictionary isn't valid, also what does that dictionary (`dictFaves`) contain ?

Comment: @Vince - thx for casting comment. dictFaves contains integer keys paired with NSString objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it using:

```
-[NSDictionary writeToURL:atomically:]
```

So, you can say:

```
[appDelegate.dictFaves writeToURL:url atomically:YES];
```

(assuming `appDelegate.dictFaves` is a valid `NSDictionary`)